# R: Lapply equivalent for Revoscaler/Revolution Enterprise?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply, revolution-r

Have Revolution Enterprise.  Want to run 2 simple but computationally intensive operations on each of 121k files in a directory, outputting to new files.  Was hoping to use some Revoscaler function that chunked/parallel processed the data similarly to lapply.  So I'd have lapply(list of files, function), but using a faster Rxdf (revoscaler) function that might actually finish, since I suspect basic lapply would never complete.

So is there a Revoscaler version of lapply?  Will running it from Revolution Enterprise automatically chunk things?

I see parlapply, mclapply (http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/parallel/clusterApply)...can I run these using cores on the same desktop?  Aws servers?  Do I get anything out of running these packages in Revoscaler if its not a native Rxdf function?  I guess then that this is a question more on what I can use as a "cluster" in this situation.

Comment: Voting to re-open. The essence of this question is "How can I iterate over files?", which is about the most programming-related thing I can imagine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`rxExec`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RevoScaleR/functions/rxExec), which behaves like `lapply` in the single-core scenario, and like `parLapply` in the multi-core/multi-process scenario. You would use it like this:

```
# vector of file names to operate on
files <- list.files()

rxSetComputeContext("localpar")
rxExec(function(fname) { 
    ...
}, fname=rxElemArg(files))
```

Here, `func` is the function that carries out the operations you want on the files; and you pass it to `rxExec` much like you would to `lapply`. The `rxElemArg` function tells `rxExec` to execute `func` on each of the different values of `files`. Setting the compute context to `"localpar"` starts up a local cluster of slave processes, so the operations will run in parallel. By default, the number of slaves is 4, but you can change this with `rxOptions(numCoresToUse)`.

How much speedup can you expect to get? That depends on your data. If your files are small and most of the time is taken up by computations, then doing things in parallel can get you a big speedup. However, if your files are large, then you may run into I/O bottlenecks especially if all the files are on the same hard disk.

Comment: files are about 150kb each so hopefully this will help.  Question has now evolved into one of my own lack of knowledge on multicore possibilities for Revolution on AWS.  Thanks much for the great answer.

Comment: tutorials from Revolution for jury-rigging the most performance out of slaves whether I'm a) on a cheap laptop or b) on reasonably bootstrapped AWS would be great, if they don't exist